# SQL Deletion of only one field with where clause

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have a table thus

```
ID stuff1  stuff2
1    10     cool
2     4     poor
3     8     cool
4     1    sucks
```

I need an sql to delete only 10 in row 1
I used->>> `delete stuff1 from mytable where ID=1` 
This works on access db but does not work on sql server
How do I do this on SQL server???

Comment: no, that does not work in Access.  DELETE acts on a Row not a column.  rather than complain about bad syntax Access, it just ignore 'stuff1' and deletes the row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to delete the row, or do you just want to remove the values from column `stuff1`?

In case you want to delete the row:

```
DELETE FROM mytable where ID = 1
```

In case you just want to remove the value of `stuff1`:

```
-- to set it to null
UPDATE mytable SET stuff1 = NULL WHERE ID = 1 

-- to set it to zero
UPDATE mytable SET stuff1 = 0 WHERE ID = 1
```

Comment: When I set a field to null this changes the data type. So what guarantees that field to take in another value having the same data type?

Comment: Setting a field to null does not change the column's data type.

Answer (score 1):

By delete one field, I'm guessing you really mean `null` the column value:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET stuff1 = null
WHERE ID=1
```

DELETE works on whole rows, not individual columns.